# How to do formatting in exported .csv from jsp?

Tags: jsp

I am successfully exporting some data from JSP to Excel as .csv file. 
I want to do some formatting. I don't know the syntax for that. Here is some part of code:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\My Documents\\ Excel\\Report.csv");

fw.append("Name");
fw.append(',');
fw.append("Address");
fw.append(',');
fw.append('\n');
```

How can I make "Name" bold. And is there any way to increase the size of the column in excel.

Answer (score 1):

Use some library for your csv processing. like 
[opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), [supercsv](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/)